# BackgroundMediaPlayer.MessageReceivedFromBackground is not working

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

When I change life cycle of the app to "Suspend and Shutdown", event MessageReceivedFromBackground from foreground is not firing?

When I change to "Suspend" and after than to "Resume" it all works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Makes sense, when you shut down the app, there is no foreground code running to receive the event.

Comment: Which code may working to receive events? And why "foreground code running to receive the event" may cause this problem? Should I unsubscribe events?

Answer (score 1):

When you shut down the app, there is no foreground code running to receive the event. To achieve this you have to use `Background Agent`

go through this links https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_create_simple_Background_Agent_in_Windows_Phone

> Note:Before using you have to figure it out that Background Agent
>   support for `BackgroundMediaPlayer`

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I found an unhandled exception in Background Task.
Sometimes the method which updates livetile cannot find information for update and crashing.

I don't know how, but background task continue to play the music, but foreground app not receiving any messages from background.

I wrapped this code to try/catch construction and voila! All works fine.